# Django error, CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have Backend = Django+Django Rest+Djoser(Token based user auth app)
Fontend = React JS + Axios.

In Local Host/Development I could do user login and authentication using token. It did'nt give error in Postman too.

In production mode It gives error as CSRF failed.

Why is so ?

I think CSRF token only needed in session authentication.

I tried removing session auth but resulted in server crash

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',

    ),
   ....
}
```

middlewares

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'shop',
    'corsheaders',
    'frontend',
    'djoser',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'users'
]
```

Comment: Are you using this api for app or for web?

Comment: api for web app (it wont refresh), I dont need session auth. How do I disable csrf token globally ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now to disable csrf check, you can create a custom authentication class `CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication` which extends from the default `SessionAuthentication` class. In this authentication class, we will override the `enforce_csrf()` check which was happening inside the actual `SessionAuthentication`.

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication

class CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication(SessionAuthentication):

    def enforce_csrf(self, request):
        return  # To not perform the csrf check previously happening
```

In your view, then you can define the `authentication_classes` to be:

```
authentication_classes = (CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication)
```

This should handle the csrf error.

Comment: Not a good solution, because now you have disabled CSRF entirely and opened your api up to x-site forgery attacks

Answer (score 1):

Add following lines in **settings.py**:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
  'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
   )
}
```

Or if you have already added these lines in your **settings.py** file, then find and remove following line from settings.py:

```
rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication
```

Source: https://khalsalabs.com/disable-csrf-verification-for-django

Comment: Not a good solution, because now you have disabled CSRF entirely and opened your api up to x-site forgery attacks